# R How to calculate the seasonal average value for each year using stackApply?

Tags: r, xts, zoo, r-raster

I wanted to calculate the seasonal average value for each year and not for the entire period. I defined my seasons as follows: DJF (December-February), MAM (March-May), JJA (June-August) and SON (September-November).

Inspired by the solution of the question of [Fredrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738413/aggregating-seasonal-means-with-the-raster-package-in), I created a index "groups" which represents the seasons then I applied the command "stackApply" but this one calculates the average seasonal value for the all of period. I explain, the final layer obtained contains only 4 raster but for my case I wanted to calculate "the seasonal average value for each year, therefore it is necessary to have 4 rasters for each year and in total the rasterstack should have 136 rasters.

Below my code

Thanks for your help

```
library(raster)
set.seed(123)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r_brick <- brick(sapply(1:408, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3))))
dim(r_brick)

dates <- seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="month")  
months <- format(dates, "%Y-%m")

groups <- function(x) {
  d <- as.POSIXlt(x)

  ans <- character(length(x))
  ans[d$mon %in%  c(11,0:1)] <- "DJF"
  ans[d$mon %in%  2:4] <- "MAM"
  ans[d$mon %in%  5:7] <- "JJA"
  ans[d$mon %in% 8:10] <- "SON"
  ans
}

data.frame(dates, groups(dates))

r_brick.s <- stackApply(r_brick, indices=groups(dates), fun=mean,na.rm=TRUE) 
nlayers(r_brick.s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
b <- brick(sapply(1:408, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3))))    
dates <- seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="month")
```

As Majid points out, if you want to group by years, you need to use these

```
years <- as.integer(format(dates, "%Y"))
months <- as.integer(format(dates, "%m"))
```

Now the months need to be grouped. Note that as you start with December you must make sure to not combine January and December of the *same* year. Rather you want to combine December of year *i* with January and February of year *i+1*. Here is one way to accomplish that (make the year start in December!)

```
n <- length(months)

# move all months back one month   
mnt <- c(months[-1], ifelse(months[n] < 12, months[n]+1, 1)) 

# move the years along
yrs <- c(years[-1],  ifelse(months[n] < 12, years[n], years[n]+1)) 

# group by trimesters using integer division (or do: floor((mnt-1) / 3))
trims <- (mnt-1) %/% 3  

# get names instead of 0, 1, 2, 3
trimnms <- c("DJF", "MAM", "JJA", "SON")[trims + 1]
```

Combine years and names

```
yt <- paste(yrs, trimnms, sep="_")
```

Use the index

```
s <- stackApply(b, indices=yt, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If the above business of moving the months backward is difficult to follow, try it out with just a few dates (the first 15 or so)

Comment: Thank you veru much Robert Hijmans for this solution. Thanks for this idea of ​​decalling year-1. That's really what I'm searching for as results

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is OK with your script, except for the groups you are generating (i.e. DJF, ...). The index you are planning to use for groups should be *unique* for each target group while, at this stage, there is no difference between JJA for 1982 and JJA for 1983 and so on!

```
#data.frame(dates, paste(substr(dates, 1,4), groups(dates), sep="_"))
idx <- paste(substr(dates, 1,4), groups(dates), sep="_")

r_brick.s <- stackApply(r_brick, indices=idx, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE) 

nlayers(r_brick.s)
#136 that is the number of seasons
```

Comment: Thank you very much Majid. Its a good idea just in this we combine January and December of the same year.
The final solution came in the second answer (Robert Hijmans).

Comment: Yes, 100% agreed!