# How to turn daily data into monthly and quarterly

Tags: r, function, zoo, converters

I am trying to convert daily data into monthly in R, could you please give me suggestions how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mirian! Please make this question *reproducible*, including code attempted, sample *small* data, any errors/warnings, and your expected output (given the sample data). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052631/aggregate-daily-data-to-month-year-intervals